# Cannot use "./" to execute a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, scripts, environment-variables

Maybe someone here would be able to help me out. Have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kubuntu) on two machines. The .bashrc and .bash_profile files are identical as the file structures on each machine is the same.

On machine 1 I run bash scripts within a terminal window with the simple: ./scriptname.sh

On machine 2, I cannot do this and must use: sh scriptname.sh
Nor can I use ./ and tab-complete the script filename.

All executable bits are set correctly, all files and folders have the correct permissions. In the header of the scripts the shebang is set correctly.

Any ideas why this would be occurring?

Cheers

Comment: also asked on [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53858/4667)
and [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13224804/7552)

Comment: Is this for root, or a non-root user?  Does `echo $SHELL` on both machines confirm that the shell is bash?

Comment: non-root user, echo $SHELL returns /bin/bash on both machines

Answer (score 3):

The errors you see may be caused by trying to run an executable on a media mounted with the "noexe" property.  Type mount, and examine the properties of the device which contains the script.  Change the /etc/fstab properties of the mount if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I have need to changed properties to `ext4    rw,relatime`

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that would cause this is if the script is not executable. I know you said the executable bit is set, but make sure:

```
chmod +x scriptname.sh
```

Comment: Nope - its definitely set right. I figure there has to be something wrong with my environmental set up (.bashrc or .bash_profile) but cant see where it has snuck in.

Answer (score 1):

I've read of various problems arising with auto-completion, not necessarily with 12.04, and the following two options seem worth trying:

First, try **disabling bash programmable completion**:  Comment-out these three lines in both `/etc/bash.bashrc` and in the user's `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
 if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
     . /etc/bash_completion
 fi
```

You may find that those lines are already commented-out with `#` in front, in which case just leave it as-is.

So secondly, try **re-installing bash-completion**:

```
sudo apt-get purge bash-completion
sudo mv /etc/bash_completion.d /etc/bash_completion.d.bak
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lars, it made no difference though.

Comment: Well, darn.  I presume you re-logged-in after doing this?